# Frequencies in a specific column of data frames in a list - R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

Let I have a list that consists of data frames(df1, df2, ..dfn).

Each data frame has a column named head1 which consist binary elements(0 and 1).

For example

`list1[[1]]$head1` is  `11010001`

`list1[[2]]$head1` is  `1000100000`

where `list1[[1]]` is `df1` and `list1[[2]]` is `df2`.

I want to get a data frame, which returns proportion of 1's in the head column of each data frame of the list1.

For the above example:

```
df[1,]=0.5
```

(four 0's and four 1's)

```
df[2,]=0.2
```

(eight 0's and two 1's)

How can I do that using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply()` in combination with `mean()` to get the proportion of `1`'s in the same column in a list of `data.frame`'s.

```
lapply(list1, function(x) mean(x[,"head1"]))
#$df1
#[1] 0.5
#
#$df2
#[1] 0.2
```

**Data**

```
list1 <- structure(list(df1 = structure(list(head1 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 1)), .Names = "head1", row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame"), 
    df2 = structure(list(head1 = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0)), .Names = "head1", row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("df1", 
"df2"))
```